# Inventory bug in Minecraft 1.17

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to drag and place stuff in a crafting table, but once I let go of my right mouse button, it simply warps back to my mouse and acts like nothing happened. I've tried turning touchscreen mode off and on but it's not doing anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. Could you explain in more detail what you mean by "drag and place stuff"? Usually, in the inventory, you need to click and release a mouse button in order to pick something up, and click and release to put it back down again.

Comment: By drag and place, I mean that I am holding down the mouse's left button. I then hold the right mouse button while hovering over a crafting table slot to place down 1 of selected item.

Answer (score 1):

The inventory bug you are experiencing is probably the result of you holding down your left mouse button.

---

**To select an item:**

Left click a stack of items to select it.

**To deselect (place down) the selected item(s):**

Left click again in an empty inventory slot.

If the slot is not empty, your selected item(s) and the items in the slot will be swapped.

---

**To place down exactly 1 item:**

Right click.

**To evenly spread out the item stack among several slots:**

You can hold down left click and move your mouse over several inventory/crafting table slots. This will evenly spread out the stack of items among the slots.

**To place 1 item from the stack into several slots:**

You can also hold down right click and move your mouse over several inventory/crafting table slots. This will place 1 item into each slot.

---

If you hold down left and right click at the same time, this will most likely cause glitching.